# Sorting a list of lists, using part of an element of the sublists

Tags: python, sorting, substring

I have a list of lists. The first element in each sublist is a chromosome eg 'chr1', 'chr5', 'chr10', 'chrX' and 'chrY'. I want to sort the sublists by chromosome number and then by X and Y. I have tried the following.

```
List.sort(key=lambda x: Set_Chr_Nr_(x[0]))
```

I am using the following def, which takes the chromosome string, removes the 'chr', converts the remainder to an int if it is a number, and asssigns a number if it is an 'X' or 'Y'.

```
def Set_Chr_Nr_ (Chr):
    """ Sort by chromosome """
    if Chr: 
        New = Chr[3:]
        if New == 'X': New = 23
        elif New == 'Y': New = 24
        elif New == 'M': New = 25
        else: New = int(New)
    else:
        New = 0
    return New
```

But it does not return the desired sort order. Instead, I get a list that starts with sublists contiaing 'chr1' but puts sublists containing 'chr10' next, not 'chr2'. What am I doing wrong here?

Example data with column header:

```
Type    OriginChr   OriginBegin OriginEnd   DestChr DestBegin   DestEnd

inversion   chr10   13105010    13105143    chr10   13104876    13105378

inversion   chr14   87902496    87902539    chr14   87902497    87902540
```

Rick

Comment: why not post that list of lists as well.

Comment: I analyse human genomes and the lists tend to be ginormous :)

Comment: @RickTearle Post a portion of it.

Comment: You can post a small part of it, coz we need some sample input.

Comment: Also note that you should check out [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - `CapWords` is generally reserved for class names, and using it for variables makes it hard to read for most used to Python. (SO even highlights them differently, presuming they are classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

```
a = ['chr1', 'chr10', 'chr5', 'chrX']
sorted(a, key=lambda x: Set_Chr_Nr_(x))
print a
```

If you want to use list.sort(), you can switch to,

```
a.sort(lambda x,y: x-y, key=lambda x: Set_Chr_Nr_(x))
```

For you original input, if the column is fixed, this will work,

```
a = [['inversion', 'chr14', 87902496, 87902539, 'chr14', 87902497, 87902540], ['inversion', 'chr10', 13105010, 13105143, 'chr10', 13104876, 13105378]]
sorted(a, key=lambda x: Set_Chr_Nr_(x[1]))
print a
```

Comment: But then I am passing a list to the def, and not a string containing the chromosome?

Comment: So you suggest that I pass the list to the function, extract the required element of the list, process it to extract the chromosome number, and return that? Why is that more likely to work than just passing the string containing the chromosome to the function?

Comment: @RickTearle you want to sort the list so you need to pass the list. you can check this url http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html, it tells several ways for sorting in python.

Comment: Looking at the page you posted, specifically the first example using lambda, it appears that a list is not being passed, but an element of a list. So I don't think you have to pass a list. I tested this on one of the other elements of the list, which is purely numeric, and the lambda approach sorted the list correctly.

Comment: @RickTearle i'm a little confused, e.g. sorted(a, key=lambda x: ...), the list a is passed to function sorted, the x is passed to lambda. i don't kown what you existly means.

Comment: My issue is not with the fact that sort requires a list. My issue is that I cannot format the lambda correctly, or cannot write the sort function Set_Chr_Nr_ () correctly, to take the string 'chrXX', extract XX, turn it in to an integer and use that integer to sort the list. The fundamental issue is that the list must have 'chr2' sorted before eg 'chr10' and that is what I cannot get the script to do.

Comment: @RickTearle you lambda works actually in this case, the wrong code is this, 'List.sort(key=lambda x: Set_Chr_Nr_(x[0]))'

Comment: I have two problems with your code. You are using sorted() which creates a copy of the list and sorts that, whereas I want to sort in situ, so I want to use list.sort(). The second is that your code passes a sublist to the sort function Set_Chr_Nr_ (), rather than an element of the sublist containing the chromosome. Your list a, is actually a list of lists, where the element containing the chromosome is present in each sublist. Is that more clear? I don't think I am explaining myself well!

Comment: So I suppose my question is does sorted() behave differently to List.sorted() when it comes to using a lambda and passing it to a function, as I am doing?

Comment: I note that in my post I talk about the chromosome element being the first element of a sublist, but in the example it is actually the second. Stupid of me. I have tested my script and I am taking the correct element to process in the function, so that is not the fundamental problem.

Comment: @RickTearle you want sort in place, that's fine, you can use list.sort(), you need to provide a cmp function as i showed in my answer, i think that's the direction.

Comment: Looking at the opening line of code I posted, I think I am doing exactly the same thing as you propose?

Comment: Doh! Your suggestion worked - my problem was elsewhere in the script, but I didn't realise it.